# Как создать стартовое окно?

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте, существует программа на с#, есть форм imc (сама программа) и есть форм start
Хочу сделать что бы форм start появлялся при запуске программы на 5 секунд, а далее исчезал и появлялась уже сама программа. подскажите пожалуйста как это удобнее сделать

Comment: Не *форм*, а *форма*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам нужно искать туториалы по "Splash Screen". Навскидку дам несколько:

- [Creating a Splash Screen in .NET with a progress bar.](http://crazorsharp.blogspot.ru/2009/06/creating-splash-screen-in-net-with.html)
- [C# Splash Screen Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/393870)
- [A Pretty Good Splash Screen in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C)